# Rotation based on touch problem

Tags: iphone, rotation

I'm making a simple dial that rotates as you drag your finger across it.   It rotates great,  but it also rotates when i touch anywhere on the screen and drag my finger.

How can i restrict the first touches to be only inside my imageview object?  or where am i going wrong?

this is my code of trouble:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav@2x.png"];

        wheelfrom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
        wheelfrom.frame =CGRectMake(10, -130, 300, 300);


        [self addSubview:wheelfrom];

    }
    return self;
}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch =[[[event allTouches] allObjects] lastObject];   
    firstLoc = [touch locationInView:self];

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch =[[[event allTouches] allObjects] lastObject];
    CGPoint curLoc = [touch locationInView:self];


    float fromAngle = atan2( firstLoc.y-wheelfrom.center.y, 
                            firstLoc.x-wheelfrom.center.x );
    float toAngle = atan2( curLoc.y-wheelfrom.center.y, 
                          curLoc.x-wheelfrom.center.x );

    float newAngle = angle + (toAngle - fromAngle);

    CGAffineTransform cgaRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newAngle);
    wheelfrom.transform = cgaRotate;


angle = newAngle;   
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try like this,

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    if(CGRectContainsPoint(wheelfrom.frame, location))
    {
         //do your things            
    }
}
```

Comment: You guys are brilliant.   Thanks so much,  i've been racking my brains over this one for a while.   It's perfect,  i really appreciate it!

Comment: One more additional question,  the image is of a cirle,  but when i select it,  it's treating it like a square in terms of the object.  Is it possible to have the transparent parts of the .png not be selectable?   or how would that work?      thanks again.

Comment: In tat case set ImageView background color as [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: I've tried to add this:    
wheelfrom.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

but it's still treating it like a square. (i can touch the corner area's of the image and it still rotates).   am i supposed to implament that somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by checking if the point of touch is within the frame of the image view.Do what you want only if its yes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  That's exactly it.   When dealing with circle image inside the image view,  is there a way to tell the frame that it's a circle and not a square?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, check the firstLoc is within your range.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.      Is there a way to setup that range so it is circular?